# .htaccess Handle uri with php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a codebase that uses the logic,

```
  if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'fr.example.com')
    {
        $_SESSION["lang"] = "fr";
    }
    elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'en.example.com')
    {
        $_SESSION["lang"] = "en";
    }
```

I want:

www.example.com should serve english

www.example.com/fr should serve french.

All the text is served from the database.

How can I use same index.php to serve english and french content based on what language is there in the URI?

Comment: What's wrong with the code, you already have? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Updated the question @OlafDietsche

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to handle this in PHP anyway, there is no need for an .htaccess file. Just use [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), e.g.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (stripos($uri, "/fr/") === 0) {
    // handle french
} elseif (stripos($uri, "/de/") === 0) {
    // handle german
} else {
    // handle english
}
```